# Hoisted variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, self-invoking-function

```
(function f(){ 
  function f(){ return 0; } 
  console.log(f()); 
  function f(){ return 1; } 
})();
```

Why is the above code giving me 1 as a result?

Comment: [........ hoisting !](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)

Answer (score 2):

You define an Immediately-invoked function expression (IIFE) called `f`. In the IIFE's scope you define two functions called `f`. Because of [hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html) the two function declarations will be moved on the top of the scope and the latter `f` will overwrite the first `f` declaration.

After hoisting the inner functions:

```
(function f(){ 
  function f(){ return 0; } 
  function f(){ return 1; } 
  console.log(f()); 
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

The IIFE is completely irrelevant here, in javascript functions and variables are hoisted, which is why you can do

```
hoisted(); // logs "foo"

function hoisted() {
  console.log("foo");
}
```

where you call the function before it is defined.
In your example the code, after hoisting, ends up being

```
  function f(){ return 0; } 
  function f(){ return 1; } 

  console.log(f());  // logs "1"
```

**[Hoisting on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)**